# trying to make my code more modular and easier to read

Tags: javascript, html, sprite, game-development

Can anyone please help me make this code more modular and easy to read? Its a bit long and repetitive in some places and i was wondering if there was maybe a way to make it easier to read and more concise.

i am trying to make a street fighter game and this is what i have so far...

```
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
 <title>Street Fighter game</title>
  <style>
  *{padding: 0; margin:0;}
  canvas{ background: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: block; margin: 0 auto;}
 </style>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css"/>
 <canvas id= "myCanvas" width="512" height="224"></canvas>
<script src="main.js"></script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

[Jeff sprite sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2usBF.png)

[Jeff mirrored sprite sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR7G8.png)

javascript code

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
console.log(canvas);
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
console.log(ctx);
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);


let fps = 60;
let jeff = new Image();
jeff.src = "images/jeff_edited.png";
let jeffMirror = new Image();
jeffMirror.src = "images/jeff_edited_flipped.png";
let p1X = 190;
let p1Y = 105;
let p2X = 260;
let p2Y = 92;
let p1FrameCount = 0;
let p1Frame = 0;
let frameSpeed = 6;

let nonInterruptibleStates = ["jeffHK", "jeffHKMirror", "jeffHP", "jeffHPMirror",
  "jeffLMK", "jeffLMKMirror", "jeffLMP", "jeffLMPMirror"];

// basic moving 
let jeffIdle = [{ x: 1, y: 0, w: 50, h: 100 }, { x: 50, y: 0, w: 50, h: 100 }, { x: 100, y: 0, w: 50, h: 100 }, { x: 149, y: 0, w: 50, h: 100 }];
let jeffIdleMirror = [{ x: 1549, y: 0, w: 50, h: 100 }, { x: 1500, y: 0, w: 50, h: 100 }, { x: 1450, y: 0, w: 50, h: 100 }, { x: 1401, y: 0, w: 50, h: 100 }];
let jeffWalking = [{ x: 203, y: 0, w: 46, h: 100 }, { x: 250, y: 0, w: 46, h: 100 }, { x: 299, y: 0, w: 46, h: 100 }, { x: 349, y: 0, w: 48, h: 100 }, { x: 399, y: 0, w: 48, h: 100 }];
let jeffWalkingMirror = [{ x: 1350, y: 0, w: 42, h: 100 }, { x: 1303, y: 0, w: 42, h: 100 }, { x: 1254, y: 0, w: 42, h: 100 }, { x: 1204, y: 0, w: 42, h: 100 }, { x: 1154, y: 0, w: 42, h: 100 }];

// extra moves
let jeffLMP = [{ x: 0, y: 116, w: 50, h: 100 }, { x: 49, y: 116, w: 65, h: 100 }, { x: 114, y: 116, w: 50, h: 100 }];
let jeffLMPMirror = [{ x: 1552, y: 116, w: 42, h: 100 }, { x: 1489, y: 116, w: 56, h: 100 }, { x: 1438, y: 116, w: 42, h: 100 }];
let jeffHP = [{ x: 167, y: 116, w: 50, h: 100 }, { x: 217, y: 116, w: 56, h: 100 }, { x: 273, y: 116, w: 77, h: 100 }, { x: 352, y: 116, w: 58, h: 100 }, { x: 408, y: 116, w: 50, h: 100 }];
let jeffHPMirror = [{ x: 1384, y: 116, w: 50, h: 100 }, { x: 1329, y: 116, w: 56, h: 100 }, { x: 1252, y: 116, w: 77, h: 100 }, { x: 1194, y: 116, w: 58, h: 100 }, { x: 1144, y: 116, w: 50, h: 100 }];
let jeffLMK = [{ x: 0, y: 246, w: 54, h: 100 }, { x: 56, y: 246, w: 73, h: 100 }, { x: 129, y: 246, w: 54, h: 100 }];
let jeffLMKMirror = [{ x: 1543, y: 246, w: 49, h: 100 }, { x: 1469, y: 246, w: 67, h: 100 }, { x: 1414, y: 246, w: 49, h: 100 }];
let jeffHK = [{ x: 190, y: 246, w: 50, h: 100 }, { x: 240, y: 246, w: 61, h: 100 }, { x: 302, y: 246, w: 74, h: 100 }, { x: 376, y: 246, w: 67, h: 100 }, { x: 443, y: 246, w: 51, h: 100 }];
let jeffHKMirror = [{ x: 1360, y: 246, w: 43, h: 100 }, { x: 1298, y: 246, w: 56, h: 100 }, { x: 1223, y: 246, w: 67, h: 100 }, { x: 1158, y: 246, w: 58, h: 100 }, { x: 1107, y: 246, w: 43, h: 100 }];

let player1State = { state: "jeffIdle", frames: 4, autoRepeat: false, nextState: "jeffIdle" };

// controls 
let leftPressed = false;
let rightPressed = false;
let upPressed = false;
let downPressed = false;
let lowP = false;
let medP = false;
let highP = false;
let lowK = false;
let medK = false;
let highK = false;


function keyDownHandler(e) {
  console.log("invoked keydownhandler");
  console.log(e);

  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    console.log("hit  up key");

    upPressed = true;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    console.log("hit  left key");
    leftPressed = true;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    downPressed = true;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 97) {
    lowP = true;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 98) {
    medP = true;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 99) {
    highP = true;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 100) {
    lowK = true;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 101) {
    medK = true;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 102) {
    highK = true;
  }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    upPressed = false;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    downPressed = false;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 97) {
    lowP = false;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 98) {
    medP = false;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 99) {
    highP = false;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 100) {
    lowK = false;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 101) {
    medK = false;
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 102) {
    highK = false;
  }
}


function drawPlayer1() {
  p1FrameCount++;
  if (p1FrameCount % frameSpeed == 0) {
    p1Frame++;
  }
  if (p1Frame >= player1State.frames && player1State.autoRepeat) {
    p1FrameCount = 0;
    p1Frame = 0;
  }
  else if (p1Frame >= player1State.frames && !player1State.autoRepeat) {
    p1FrameCount = 0;
    p1Frame = 0;
    frameSpeed = 8;
    if (p1X > p2X) {
      if (player1State.nextState == "jeffIdle" || player1State.nextState == "jeffIdleMirror") {
        player1State = { state: "jeffIdleMirror", frames: 4, autoRepeat: true, nextState: "jeffIdleMirror" }
      }
    }
    else {
      if (player1State.nextState == "jeffIdle" || player1State.nextState == "jeffIdleMirror") {
        player1State = { state: "jeffIdle", frames: 4, autoRepeat: true, nextState: "jeffIdle" }
      }
    }
  }

  console.log("Player state value" + player1State.state);
  if (player1State.state == "jeffIdle") {
    ctx.drawImage(jeff, jeffIdle[p1Frame].x, jeffIdle[p1Frame].y,
      jeffIdle[p1Frame].w, jeffIdle[p1Frame].h, p1X, p1Y,
      jeffIdle[p1Frame].w, jeffIdle[p1Frame].h);
  }
  else if (player1State.state == "jeffIdleMirror") {
    ctx.drawImage(jeffMirror, jeffIdleMirror[p1Frame].x,
      jeffIdleMirror[p1Frame].y, jeffIdleMirror[p1Frame].w,
      jeffIdleMirror[p1Frame].h, p1X, p1Y, jeffIdleMirror[p1Frame].w,
      jeffIdleMirror[p1Frame].h);
  }
  else if (player1State.state == "jeffWalking") {
    ctx.drawImage(jeff, jeffWalking[p1Frame].x,
      jeffWalking[p1Frame].y, jeffWalking[p1Frame].w,
      jeffWalking[p1Frame].h, p1X, p1Y, jeffWalking[p1Frame].w,
      jeffWalking[p1Frame].h);
  }
  else if (player1State.state == "jeffWalkingMirror") {
    ctx.drawImage(jeffMirror, jeffWalkingMirror[p1Frame].x,
      jeffWalkingMirror[p1Frame].y, jeffWalkingMirror[p1Frame].w,
      jeffWalkingMirror[p1Frame].h, p1X, p1Y, jeffWalkingMirror[p1Frame].w,
      jeffWalkingMirror[p1Frame].h);
  }
  else if (player1State.state == "jeffLMP") {
    ctx.drawImage(jeff, jeffLMP[p1Frame].x,
      jeffLMP[p1Frame].y, jeffLMP[p1Frame].h,
      p1X + 2, p1Y, jeffLMP[p1Frame].w, jeffLMP[p1Frame].h);
  }
  else if (player1State.state == "jeffLMPMirror") {

    if (p1Frame == 1) {
      ctx.drawImage(jeff, jeffLMP[p1Frame].x,
        jeffLMP[p1Frame].y, jeffLMP[p1Frame].h,
        p1X - 14, p1Y, jeffLMP[p1Frame].w, jeffLMP[p1Frame].h);
    }

    else {
      ctx.drawImage(jeff, jeffLMP[p1Frame].x,
        jeffLMP[p1Frame].y, jeffLMP[p1Frame].h,
        p1X, p1Y, jeffLMP[p1Frame].w, jeffLMP[p1Frame].h);
    }

    33
  }
  else if (player1State.state == "jeffHP") {
    ctx.drawImage(jeff, jeffHP[p1Frame].x,
      jeffHP[p1Frame].y, jeffHP[p1Frame].h,
      p1X + 2, p1Y, jeffHP[p1Frame].w, jeffHP[p1Frame].h);
  }
  if (player1State.state == "jeffHPMirror") {
    if (p1Frame == 0) {
      ctx.drawImage(jeffMirror, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].x, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].y,
        jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].w - 5, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].h,
        p1X - 5, p1Y, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].w,
        jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].h);
    }
    else if (p1Frame == 1) {
      ctx.drawImage(jeffMirror, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].x, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].y,
        jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].w, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].h,
        p1X - 6, p1Y, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].w,
        jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].h);
    }
    else if (p1Frame == 2) {
      ctx.drawImage(jeffMirror, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].x, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].y,
        jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].w, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].h,
        p1X - 27, p1Y, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].w,
        jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].h);
    }
    else if (p1Frame == 3) {
      ctx.drawImage(jeffMirror, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].x, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].y,
        jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].w, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].h,
        p1X - 8, p1Y, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].w,
        jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].h);
    }
    else {
      ctx.drawImage(jeffMirror, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].x, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].y,
        jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].w, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].h,
        p1X + 1, p1Y, jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].w,
        jeffHPMirror[p1Frame].h);
    }

  }
  else if (player1State.state == "jeffLMK") {
    if (p1Frame == 0) {
      ctx.drawImage(jeff, jeffLMK[p1Frame].x, jeffLMK[p1Frame].y,
        jeffLMK[p1Frame].w, jeffLMK[p1Frame].h,
        p1X - 7, p1Y - 1, jeffLMK[p1Frame].w,
        jeffLMK[p1Frame].h);
    }
    else if (p1Frame == 1) {
      ctx.drawImage(jeff, jeffLMK[p1Frame].x, jeffLMK[p1Frame].y,
        jeffLMK[p1Frame].w, jeffLMK[p1Frame].h,
        p1X - 18, p1Y - 1, jeffLMK[p1Frame].w,
        jeffLMK[p1Frame].h);
    }
    else {
      ctx.drawImage(jeff, jeffLMK[p1Frame].x, jeffLMK[p1Frame].y,
        jeffLMK[p1Frame].w, jeffLMK[p1Frame].h,
        p1X - 7, p1Y - 1, jeffLMK[p1Frame].w,
        jeffLMK[p1Frame].h);
    }
  }
  else if (player1State.state == "jeffLMKMirror") {
    if (p1Frame == 0) {
      ctx.drawImage(jeffMirror, jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].x, jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].y,
        jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].w, jeffLMKMirror[p1Prame].h,
        p1X, p1Y - 1, jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].w,
        jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].h);
    }
    else if (p1Frame == 1) {
      ctx.drawImage(jeffMirror, jeffLMKMirror[p1Prame].x, jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].y,
        jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].w, jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].h,
        p1X - 6, p1Y - 1, jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].w,
        jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].h);
    }
    else {
      ctx.drawImage(jeffMirror, jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].x, jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].y,
        jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].w, jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].h,
        p1X, p1Y - 1, jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].w,
        jeffLMKMirror[p1Frame].h);
    }

  } else if (player1State.state == "jeffHK") {
    if (p1Frame == 0) {
      ctx.drawImage(jeff, jeffHK[p1Frame].x, jeffHK[p1Frame].y,
        jeffHK[p1Frame].w, jeffHK[p1Frame].h,
        p1X, p1Y - 1, jeffHK[p1Frame].w,
        jeffHK[p1Frame].h);
    }
    else if (p1Frame == 1) {
      ctx.drawImage(jeff, jeffHK[p1Frame].x, jeffHK[p1Frame].y,
        jeffHK[p1Frame].w, jeffHK[p1Frame].h,
        p1X - 4, p1Y - 1, jeffHK[p1Frame].w,
        jeffHK[p1Frame].h);
    }
    else if (p1Frame == 2) {
      ctx.drawImage(jeff, jeffHK[p1Frame].x, jeffHK[p1Frame].y,
        jeffHK[p1Frame].w, jeffHK[p1Frame].h,
        p1X - 1, p1Y - 1, jeffHK[p1Frame].w,
        jeffHK[p1Frame].h);
    }
    else if (p1Frame - 3) {
      ctx.drawImage(jeff, jeffHK[p1Frame].x, jeffHK[p1Frame].y,
        jeffHK[p1Frame].w, jeffHK[p1Frame].h,
        p1X - 1, p1Y - 1, jeffHK[p1Frame].w,
        jeffHK[p1Frame].h);
    }
    else {
      ctx.drawImage(jeff, jeffHK[p1Frame].x, jeffHK[p1Frame].y,
        jeffHK[p1Frame].w, jeffHK[p1Frame].h,
        p1X, p1Y - 1, jeffHK[p1Frame].w,
        jeffHK[p1Frame].h);


    }
  }
}




function controls() {

  if (leftPressed) {

    if (p1X >= -6) {
      p1X -= 2;
    }

    if (player1State.nextState == "jeffIdle" || player1State.nextState == "jeffIdleMirror") {
      if (p1X < p2X) {
        player1State = { state: "jeffWalking", frames: 5, autoRepeat: false, nextState: "jeffIdle" }
      }
      else {
        player1State = { state: "jeffWalkingMirror", frames: 5, autoRepeat: false, nextState: "jeffIdleMirror" }
      }
    }
  }
  else if (rightPressed) {
    if (p1X <= 470) {
      p1X += 2;
    }

    if (player1State.nextState == "jeffIdle" || player1State.nextState == "jeffIdleMirror") {
      if (p1X < p2X) {
        player1State = { state: "jeffWalking", frames: 5, autoRepeat: false, nextState: "jeffIdle" }
      }
      else {
        player1State = { state: "jeffWalkingMirror", frames: 5, autoRepeat: false, nextState: "jeffIdleMirror" }
      }
    }
  }

  else if ((lowP || medP) && !nonInterruptibleStates.includes(player1State.state)) {
    lowP = false;
    medP = false;
    if (p1X > p2X) {
      player1State = { state: "jeffLMPMirrior", frames: 3, autoRepeat: false, nextState: "jeffIdleMirror" }
    }
    else {
      player1State = { state: "jeffLMP", frames: 3, autoRepeat: false, nextState: "jeffIdle" }
    }
  }

  else if (highP && !nonInterruptibleStates.includes(player1State.state)) {
    highP = false;
    if (p1X > p2X) {
      player1State = { state: "jeffHPMirrior", frames: 5, autoRepeat: false, nextState: "jeffIdleMirror" }
    }
    else {
      player1State = { state: "jeffHP", frames: 5, autoRepeat: false, nextState: "jeffIdle" }
    }
  }
  else if ((lowK || medK) && !nonInterruptibleStates.includes(player1State.state)) {
    lowK = false;
    medK = false;
    if (p1X > p2X) {
      player1State = { state: "jeffLMKMirrior", frames: 3, autoRepeat: false, nextState: "jeffIdleMirror" }
    }
    else {
      player1State = { state: "jeffLMK", frames: 3, autoRepeat: false, nextState: "jeffIdle" }
    }
  }

  else if (highK && !nonInterruptibleStates.includes(player1State.state)) {
    highP = false;
    if (p1X > p2X) {
      player1State = { state: "jeffHKMirrior", frames: 5, autoRepeat: false, nextState: "jeffIdleMirror" }
    }
    else {
      player1State = { state: "jeffHK", frames: 5, autoRepeat: false, nextState: "jeffIdle" }
    }
  }



    else if (!rightPressed && !leftPressed
    && player1State != "jeffLMP" &&
    player1State.state != "jeffLMPMirror" &&
    player1State.state != " jeffHP" &&
    player1State.state != "jeffHPMirror" &&
    player1State.state != "jeffLMK" &&
    player1State.state != "jeffLMKMirror" &&
    player1State.state != "jeffHK" &&
    player1State.state != "jeffHKMirror"
  ) {
     if (p1X < p2X) {
      player1State = { state: "jeffIdle", frames: 4, autoRepeat: false, nextState: "jeffIdle" }
    }
      else {
      player1State = { state: "jeffIdleMirror", frames: 4, autoRepeat: false, nextState: 
  "jeffIdleMirror" }
    }
     if (p1Frame > player1State.frames) {
      p1Frame = 0;
      }
    }

  }






    function draw() {
     setTimeout(function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
     ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(80, 152, 216)";
     ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
     controls();
     drawPlayer1();

     }, 1000 / fps);
   }
     draw();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

identify code you are repeating over and over, like drawImage() and make a function where you pass the parameters like: function draw(frameNumber, playerState) and make 1 drawImage() call with passed parameters

avoid using the "else if" and use things like "switch" with "breaks;".

most of the time the "else" is not needed if your conditions are always different.

always try to ABSTRACT your code